# Hive query fails on jdbc

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, cloudera

My failing query is like

```
select * from example_table where (...) OR (...) OR (...)
```

where (...) denoting simple boolean operations.
The same query successfully runs on Hue interface, however; it fails on jdbc driver where I connect to hiveserver2 thrift port with class "`com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver`".
The java failing message is that:

```
FeatureNotSupportedException: Error message not found: FEATURE_NOT_SUPPORTED. Can't find bundle for base name com.cloudera.hive.sqlengine.SQLEngineMessages, locale en_US
```

By the way, I take this error in eclipse and a simple query like "show tables" or a simple select statement successfully runs on my eclipse.
Thanks,

Comment: That's the Cloudera driver that you are using, not the regular Apache Hive driver. You might try that one instead ==> class `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver` from `hive-jdbc-standalone.jar` plus `hadoop-common.jar` and `commons-configuration.jar` in CLASSPATH, possibly `hadoop-auth.jar` also *(required for Kerberos)*

Comment: ...plus a Windows version of Hadoop run-time somewhere, and system props `-Dhadoop.home.dir=C:/path/to/hadoop`and `-Djava.library.path=C:/path/to/hadoop/bin`

Comment: BTW, Hue does *not* use JDBC...

Comment: About the error message itself: open the JAR file for the Cloudera driver, with any Zip utility *(7Zip, WinZip, etc.)* and follow the path `com/cloudera/hive/sqlengine/` -- there should be a `SQLEngineMessages.properties` there. If it's actually there, then maybe you've got a CLASPATH issue. If it's not there *(maybe in another folder??)* then it smells like a bug in the JAR build.